# Getting old data with JPA

Tags: java, jpa, eclipselink

I'm getting old data with JPA, even if I disable the cache. I guess is because the resource is configured to be RESOURCE_LOCAL, but I'm not sure.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd">
    <persistence-unit name="AppPU" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
        <provider>org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider</provider>
        <class>com.myentities.User</class>
        <properties>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/mydatabase"/>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="*****"/>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="user1"/>
            <property name="eclipselink.logging.level" value="FINEST"/>
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

My code that is getting old info about the user:

```
public List<User> findAll(App app) {       
        getEntityManager().getTransaction().begin();        
        Query q = getEntityManager().createQuery("SELECT t1 FROM User t1 WHERE t1.app.idApp=:idApp");
        q.setParameter("idApp", app.getIdApp());
        getEntityManager().flush();
        getEntityManager().getTransaction().commit();
        List resultList = q.getResultList();        
        return resultList;
    }
```

My entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "user")
@Cache (
     type=CacheType.NONE
     )
public class User implements Serializable {

// some attributtes

}
```

Anybody has some idea of what is going on?

#### UPDATE 1

The *begin*, *flush* and *commit* methods were just acts of desperation! I know it's not needed.

I forgot to say something **important**: the test I make is to add a user record **direct on database console** and then try to see it through my webapp, which is **not showing the new user**. That is the "old data" I mentioned, it only displays "old users".

I already tried to put this on **persistence.xml** and I didn't see any difference in the results:

```xml
<property name="eclipselink.cache.shared.default" value="false"/>
<property name="eclipselink.cache.size.default" value="0"/>
<property name="eclipselink.cache.type.default" value="None"/>
```

So is something else…

Comment: 1) You do not need to start/flush/commit any transaction when only querying. 2) Where does the 'sistema' object come from? Why is the 'app' argument not used in the method?

Comment: is that the entire method?  the flush and commit do not make any sense there.  In what way is the data old?  What's wrong with it?  What else have you done inside the scope of that EntityManager?  What are all of the calls/changes made between opening and closing the EM?  One guesses you've let the in memory state of your entities fall out of synch with the database.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

There are a few suggestions posted already such as ensuring the shared cache is off, and to manage back references so that the cache is consistent.  These are for specific situations that could be occuring, but you have not provided enough to say what is really happening.

Another that is specific but seems possible based on your getEntityManager() usage, is if you are reusing the EntityManager instance without clearing it.  The EntityManager holds a references to all managed entities since the EM is required to return the same instance on subsequent query and find calls to maintain identity.

If this is not done already, will want to clear the EntityManager or obtain a new one at certain points to release the memory and managed entities.

Comment: You were right! The problem was at my EntityManager. It was not about EclipseLink Cache or anything like that. Thanks!

Comment: Could anyone pls, describe a bit more on clearing EM and reusing it. I am new to JPA. My problem is if i modify two rows in a table manually(to test), the applications, fetch the new data for first modified row but old data for second modified row. I am doing em.clear() before em.ceateNamedQuery(....). Is that fine?

Comment: @Dexter My suggestion is that if possible, avoid using DML to execute CUD, because you may encounter the [Stale Data](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/Caching#Stale_Data) problem. And if you have to, call `clear()` or `refresh()` after the DML execution, you can find more information in the link.

Answer (score 3):

First off, don't use,

```
@Cache(type=CacheType.NONE)
or,
<property name="eclipselink.cache.size.default" value="0"/>
or,
<property name="eclipselink.cache.type.default" value="None"/>
```

just set,

```
@Cache(shared=false)
or,
<property name="eclipselink.cache.shared.default" value="false"/>
```

Second, where is your EntityManager coming from?  Do you create a new one per request/transaction?  If you don't then everything read in the EntityManager will be in its (L1) cache.  You need to call clear() or create a new one.

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
<property name="eclipselink.cache.shared.default" value="false"/>
<property name="eclipselink.cache.size.default" value="0"/>
<property name="eclipselink.cache.type.default" value="None"/>
```

or

```
@Cache(shared=false)
```

Answer (score 1):

As opposed to the caching answer (which I will have to try) you're likely running into a situation where your referenced entity isn't updated.

```
@Entity
Class Parent
{
  @OneToOne(Cascade.ALL)//Or only Merge, whatever you're needs
  Child child;
}

@Entity
Class Child
{
  Parent parent;
  ... Values
}
```

Upon saving the Child you need to update your reference to Parent so that the Memory Model (cache) matches the database. It is fairly frustrating, but the way I've dealt with this is to cascade only from the parent.

```
public void saveChild(Child child)
{
  child.getParent().setChild(this); //or DTO Code, whatever
  EntityManager.merge(parent); //cascades to the child.
  //If you're manually cascading (why?) 
  //EntityManager.merge(child);
}
```

This will cascade if you set it up--what I've seen is that the reverse cascade (the child merge causes a cascade to the parent) has not been reliable--stemming from my lack of knowledge in the subject.

In short--if you handle the merge in your data-layer explicitly, the problem goes away. I'm reluctant to disable caching as it could have a significant impact in large applications, thus, I went this route. Good luck, and please let us know your approach.

Answer (score 0):

1) Refine the code

```
public List<User> findAll(App app) {   
    Query q = getEntityManager().createQuery("SELECT t1 FROM User t1 WHERE    t1.app.idApp=:idApp");    q.setParameter("idApp", app.getIdApp());                 
    List resultList = q.getResultList();            
    return resultList;    
}
```

2)Remove @Cache (type=CacheType.NONE) from your entity class

3) No need to change persistence.xml

Answer (score 0):

The usage of EntityManager is the key. I've reached the perfect solution after months:

- Use a common DEFAULT entity manager for all READS of an entity. This means create a separate entity manager for each entity.
- Create a new entity manager for each write/update/delete operation of each entity. Use begin/commit for transaction of that new entity. Close the entity manager after the operation finish.
- The node point: Clear the DEFAULT entity manager (reader one) after you commit and close the writer entity manager. This means only clear after write; not before each read.