# Spring data and spring JDBC return a different value

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jdbc, jdbctemplate

everyone! I have a problem. I use Spring Data in my project with some microservices.
One of them changes a row in DB. Then in my microservice I check that row. The main problem is that findById() method of Spring Data return old, not changed value.
I put a breakpoin, my eyes see one value in DB, but repository give me another one.
After some experiments I decided to try to write this query throught Spring JBDC. And now - everything is okay.
This is Spring Data query:

```
Optional<MessageLog> byId = messageLogRepository.findById(id);
```

This is Spring JDBC:

```
public MessageLog findByIdJdbc(String id) {
    SqlParameterSource sqlParameterSource = new MapSqlParameterSource("id", id);
    String findByIdSQL = "SELECT * from MESSAGESLOG where ID = :id";
    return namedParameterJdbcTemplate.queryForObject(findByIdSQL, sqlParameterSource, rowMapper);
    }
```

Could you, please, give me an explanation or an article? I think that the problem can be in cache. But did not find an answer.

Comment: does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51739841/how-to-disable-spring-hibernate-hazelcast-joint-cache

Comment: @JAsgarov no. I don't use second level cache. As I know it is disable by default. But thank you!

Comment: will this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7933617/getting-old-data-with-jpa

Comment: Could you try clearing the entityManager before calling findById to see what happens: entityManager.clear();

Comment: @JavaLearner1, Meac Bannout thank you! Now it's work. But could you give me a complete explanation? As I understand Hibernate has first level cache or PersistenceContext which save all entities in one session. I had it in one state, then another micoservice changes the row in DB, but I still got the the same entity. 
entityManager.clear() - clear this context and everything is fine. But as I understand in my case: Spring JDBC works with DB directly?
And as I use Spring data through CrudRepository I needed to add "EntityManager entityManager". Is it a good way? Or I can use some annotation?

Answer (score 0):

As guys in comments said: I need to write:

```
entityManager.clear()
```